# Check if graph contains an isomorphic subgraph to cycle C3/of lenght 3

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Check with the matrix multiplication method whether the simple graph presented in the form of an adjacency matrix
contains an isomorphic subgraph to cycle C3
Having such a graph and such a neighborhood matrix corresponding to it:
[sample graph and its matrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxbOV.png)

```
| 0 0 1 1 |
| 0 0 0 1 |
| 1 0 0 1 |
| 1 1 1 0 |
```

How do I multiply these matrices to see anything and be able to draw some conclusions?

Comment: These should all answer your question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152197/given-an-nn-adjacency-matrix-calculate-the-number-of-triangles-in-a-graph
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996705/if-a-is-the-adjacency-matrix-of-a-graph-g-and-a3-has-a-1-on-the-diagon
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188366/finding-the-total-number-of-triangle

Comment: @BrandonduPreez If one graph has a triangle, and the second one too, that means that they are isomorphic?